# Why is “HADAT” the solution to the crossword clue "went after"?

Tags: crossword-clues, explanation

I was doing crossword from NY Times, from Mon, Feb 11, 2019 by Howard Barkin + Will Shortz and I got the following clue.

> Went after

The answer is "HADAT". However, I can not find definition for HADAT that fits the clue.
Various links (ex. [reference](https://www.anagrammer.com/crossword/answer/hadat)) shows me this is a common word used in crosswords.

Why is the answer "HADAT and how does the clue "went after" fit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I think the answer is actually 'Had at' - as in '[had a go at (attack)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+at) (someone)', which would mean you 'went after' them.
>
> The word 'hadat' itself isn't a word, but putting 'had' and 'at' together will give you the answer.

Comment: mmhm. For reasons like this very example, I enjoy the nytimes crosswords.

Comment: Did the clue say (5) or (3,2) ?  These indicate that it's a five letter word, or a three+two letter words

Comment: @CSM the OP doesn’t say, but I presume from knowing this is the intended answer it would have been 3,2

Comment: @CSM:  NYT crosswords (and American crosswords more generally) don't provide word lengths in the clues.

Comment: UK crosswords generally do provide the lengths; I thought this was standard international practice. It seems I was mistaken in my assumptions.

Comment: This isn't really correct.  @JLRishe has it correct

Comment: @Kevin no this is correct, but I would say the other answer is perhaps more correct. Please note that I'm not saying it means 'have a go at', thats just an example of how it can be used. The link even takes you to a page which defines 'have at' - which is what the other answer says. It's just more explicit in their answer

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil But "have at" and "have a go at" are not the same thing.  One means to attack, the other means to attempt.  At least in AmE

Comment: @Kevin 'have a go at' can also mean attack. And I'm not saying the answer is that, I'm saying the answer is 'have at' which is a synonym of 'have a go at'. I'm using 'have a go at' as an explanation of what 'have at' means. I'll make an edit to clarify what I mean

Comment: Rather obscure past tense.  "Have at you" is quite common. it is a gentlemanly way of saying "I'll f'n do you, Jimmy!".  Don't hear a lot of "en garde" any more though.... Bounders and cads deserve no less.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer explains this in terms of a four word expression, but that's not really necessary:

> From the American Heritage Dictionary
>  **have at**
>
>  *Attack; also, make an attempt at. For example, Urging the dog on, he said, “Go on, Rover, have at him,” or It's time to have at straightening out these files.*
>
>  This is commonly used in the exhortation "have at it" which is another way of saying "go for it"

Comment: I think 'have at' is just a shortened version of 'have a go at' but yes this is the same idea

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil "Have at" is definition 27b for "have (v.)" in the OED, with citations dating back to 1400. "Have a go at" might be a more modern variation of it.

Comment: Scrolled down to find this comment; this should be top IMO. "Have at it" is much closer than "Have a go at it" in terms of what the clue's looking for

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil "have at" significantly predates "have a go at"